# nodejs, passportjs local strategy is not running

Tags: node.js

I am using express and passport to build a rest api backend and it seems that my localStrategy is not getting called on request.

```
var express     = require('express');
var passport    = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var app         = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;



app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index.ejs');

});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log('login /GET');
    res.render('login.ejs');
});

passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password'
},
    function(username, password, done) {
        console.log('local strategy');
        return done(null, {username : 'username'});

    }
));

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        console.log('auth run');

        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('listenting http://localhost:' + port);
```

My login request fires which shows message in console but that's it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a couple things.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

You may need to deal with serializing your user object as well.